# SOAP-based Web Service in Sencha

Tags: web-services, soap, sencha-touch-2

How should I call a SOAP based web service using Sencha?

I was able to call my service using [JavaScriptSoapClient](http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Ext JS, the SOAP proxy is probably what you want.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.soap.Proxy

Comment: Thanks...this is help full..can you please give me a example mean running code so that i can understand.

Comment: All you have to do is search Google... http://www.sencha.com/blog/taking-a-look-at-the-new-sencha-soap-data-proxy

Comment: i have this url http://railapps.firstgroup.com:8080/FirstGroupRailApps/services/RailAppsWS

Answer (score 0):

Check this out on the Sencha Blog: 
http://www.sencha.com/blog/taking-a-look-at-the-new-sencha-soap-data-proxy